# Can i route all traffic from a specific web browser through a specific NIC

Tags: browser, ip, traffic

I have a Sony Viao with LAN, wireless and mobile broadband. I am a software developer often working at a customers address on their LAN. Is it possible to dedicate a browser like chrome to a specific IP route such as the mobile broadband.

This would allow me to use chrome when on the customers sites to view websites blocked by the customers rules. e.g. Web based email clients like hotmail.

Note that this is different from adding a route to a specific site through a specified nic using a routing table. I want to specify my local application to bind to a specific NIC.

Any ideas. This will help not only me but contract software developers everywhere. Something is surely available.

Thanks

Dave

Comment: Could you set up some sort of application like fiddler to act as a proxy and get that route traffic through the address of the NIC in question?

Answer (score 0):

Programmatically, restricting yourself to a specific NIC is done by calling `bind()` with the NIC's IP address after creating the socket but before connecting.  If you omit this step, the sockts interface will use a local IP address of 0.0.0.0 ("any") and a local port number of 0 ("any").

I don't believe there is any option in Chrome, FireFox, or MSIE to support this.  You could always grab the source, change it, and compile it yourself.  (Not fun, I know.)

Or, as Mr.Moose says, you can run a local http proxy and modify it's code to bind outgoing connections to the desired NIC.

Updating your routing table is probably easiest even if it's not exactly what you want.